# What is a good method to perform UI review?

Tags: user-interface, user-experience, user-interaction

I am a UI/UX designer. Currently I got interviewed for a post and now they’ve given me an Exercise where I am supposed to do a complete UI review/Audit/Analysis of their product. I need some suggestions to do the exercise:

1. What medium do you think is best for presenting such a review? A video, An audio with visuals, or a document highlighting issues in UI with callouts?
2. What are the key points that need to be covered in such a review?

So that I submit the best exercise and get selected. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should know that UI/UX is not my area of expertise. But I've been directly or indirectly involved with it enough to know that it's not an exact science. People will often debate about what is the best for the user. Just remember that two users themselves might not agree on something.

So what I think is important is that you genuinely take the role of a user, try using the product imagining a scenario where you want to accomplish something. If you do it right, you should have some feedback on what works well and what could be improved. It's your opinion, the important part is that you can back them up with common sense or valid arguments.

As for the medium, I'd say that you should choose the one that communicates your views the best. I'd rather read through well organized text than go through a poor video. You'd probably want to impress, so whatever you choose, do it well! If the UX design was documented upfront, you would normally use that as the basis for your review. So look up UX design tools, you might be able to use one of them.

If you have time, a background in UML modeling might be helpful, particularly the ICONIX methodology, which encourages exploring different "what if" scenarios, rather than just desiging for the standard (most common) path. Also assuming that you've already looked up online resources describing common best practices.